# Orthogonality of a 4x4 matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, dct, orthogonal

I am working on a MATLAB task which deals with stain removal.

**What am I doing?**
I have been given a 4x4 matrix. I have then been told that it may well be orthogonal. I have to make it prove that the DCT matrix is actually orthogonal.

This is the given DCT matrix:

```
0.5000   0.5000   0.5000   0.5000   
0.6533   0.2706  -0.2706  -0.6533
0.5000  -0.5000  -0.5000   0.5000  
0.2706  -0.6533   0.6533  -0.2706
```

Here's the code:

```
function [U, C, G] = UFGDCT(N)
%
%   Compute the matrices for DCT (-?-)
%
%   U is the unitary "in-between" matrix
%   C is the matrix of the DCT
%   G is the inverse of F
%
    C = zeros(N);
    for row = 0:N-1
        for col = 0:N-1
            C(row+1, col+1) = cos(pi*row*(col+(1/2))/N);
        end
    end
    for cols = 0:N-1
        C(1,cols+1) = C(1,cols+1)/sqrt(2);
    end
    C = C*sqrt(2/N);
    U = C;
    G = C';
end
```

**How can I do it in the simplest way?** I have tried to search about finding orthogonality of a matrix, but didn't get the luch. I could not find anything that could be helpful.

**RESULT:**

```
mat*mat'
mat'*mat

ans =

    1.0000         0         0         0
         0    1.0001         0         0
         0         0    1.0000         0
         0         0         0    1.0001


ans =

    1.0000    0.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
    0.0000    1.0000   -0.0000   -0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    1.0000    0.0000
   -0.0000   -0.0000    0.0000    1.0000
```

Comment: Please include text as [formatted text](/help/formatting) instead of an image. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks for that :-)

Comment: In case it helps, you can obtain that matrix simply as `dct(eye(N))`

Comment: The results you got show that it's orthogonal enough - subject to numerical errors. You got an identity matrix both times, and that's what you wanted. You can also do `norm(mat'*mat)-eye(4)` and `norm(mat*mat')-eye(4)` - you want to get small numbers both times, and you will. So all is good.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check the orthogonality, you can use `mat*mat'` and `mat'*mat` to see if it is an identity matrix

```
>> mat*mat'
ans =

   1.0000        0        0        0
        0   1.0001        0  -0.0000
        0        0   1.0000  -0.0000
        0  -0.0000  -0.0000   1.0001

>> mat'*mat
ans =

   1.0000e+00  -2.4018e-17  -3.7377e-18  -2.5250e-05
  -2.4018e-17   1.0000e+00  -2.5250e-05  -3.7377e-18
  -3.7377e-18  -2.5250e-05   1.0000e+00  -2.4018e-17
  -2.5250e-05  -3.7377e-18  -2.4018e-17   1.0000e+00
```

You will see that a tolerance should be set to determine if `mat` is orthogonal

```
>> mat*mat'-eye(4)
ans =

            0            0            0            0
            0   5.0500e-05            0  -3.7377e-18
            0            0            0  -2.7756e-17
            0  -3.7377e-18  -2.7756e-17   5.0500e-05

>> mat'*mat-eye(4)
ans =

   2.5250e-05  -2.4018e-17  -3.7377e-18  -2.5250e-05
  -2.4018e-17   2.5250e-05  -2.5250e-05  -3.7377e-18
  -3.7377e-18  -2.5250e-05   2.5250e-05  -2.4018e-17
  -2.5250e-05  -3.7377e-18  -2.4018e-17   2.5250e-05
```

**Data**

```
mat = [0.5000   0.5000   0.5000   0.5000   
0.6533   0.2706  -0.2706  -0.6533
0.5000  -0.5000  -0.5000   0.5000  
0.2706  -0.6533   0.6533  -0.2706];
```

Comment: You should use `'` instead of `.'` here, in case the matrix is complex

Comment: @LuisMendo That's true! Thanks for feedback

Comment: Also, note that the test you include is not enough. You should also check that the matrix is square (or compute `mat'*mat` in addition to `mat*mat'`)

Comment: Thanks alot @ThomasIsCoding, you made it as simple as possible. By the way, I have question: In terms of originality in a matrix, how should it be explained? Because, I know that in vectors that if two lines are orthogonal it means that they are perpendicular to each other. So I assume in the matrix; it's orthogonal because it has the same values in digonal, where the zeros are located around?

Comment: @Henrik.A Perhaps this could help https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrthogonalMatrix.html

Comment: @LuisMendo , ThomasIsCoding, but the thing is which code do I have to use to prove its orthogonality, with or without -eye(4)? Also, I am getting different results, can you please check? I've updated my thread. Is that correct?

Comment: Just subtract the matrix product and the identity matrix, as Thomas does, and see if all the entries in the result are very small. Ideally they should be zero, but they may not be due to numerical inaccuracies with floating-point numbers

Comment: @LuisMendo While nearly always using `.'` over `'` is encouraged for purely structural changes, I think its usage here is beneficial since the formula does generalize over the complex numbers in the case of unitary matrices. Now if the domain of the linear operators is limited to be over purely the reals, I'd place that as a separate test and keep the general formula "clean" (opinion, of course).